# Why is disclosing that you offer no warranties so prevalent in documents?

Tags: software, licensing, non-disclosure, warranties

I was signing an NDA and noticed that there was a clause on the owner offering no warranty relating to the document. I never particularly understood this. It is often prevalent in copyleft licenses and I was wondering if there was a legal reason that this has to be stated so often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you buy something and it somehow goes bad, you might suffer a loss. For example, if a (network) router dies, you might not be able to access the internet and could lose money because you miss a big sale, or a customer can't contact you. The router-manufacturer might then be liable to you for the loss that you suffered because of that defect. In some cases, the manufacturer cannot disclaim liability (so you check [§3 of RCW Chapter 62a.2](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=62A.2)), for example, if the router explodes because of manufacturing negligence, the manufacturer can't say "you can't sue me". But sometimes, they can disclaim liability, so the manufacturer does what is required in [RCW 62A.2-316](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=62A.2-316), which essentially requires you to clearly and prominently disclaim liability. Liability for business loss could thus be disclaimed, but you have to actually do so (since it is foreseeable that a router might fail and that such failure could cause a customer to suffer a business loss). Of course, disclaimer language tends to be very wide-ranging, and would include the a disclaimer of pain and suffering loss from a Netflix watch-party getting cancelled because your router failed.

It is ubiquitous in software because nobody has ever written completely idiot- and bulletproof software. By adding such disclaimers, you significantly reduce the risk of getting sued.

Comment: It is worth noting that 2-316 applies by its terms only to good which are tangible personal property, but there is a concern (a legitimate one) that the common law of contract could apply these principles to intangible property and rights.

Comment: We tend to encode that stuff in legislation, so Titles 11, 42, 48, 64 cover other kinds of disclaimers. Thus a whole chapter 11.86 on disclaimer of interest in trusts and probate...

Comment: This also happens. My point is simply that 2-316 is one specific provision that doesn't directly apply to the situation in the question.